# I Lost my original ac adaptor, Can i use other model of power supply?

Tags: power-supply, ac-adapter

I Lost my original ac adaptor, Can i use other model of power supply? the Output of the original ac adapter is 7.3v = 1.75A and the one i want to use is 7.9v=1.4A can i use this adapter?

Comment: No; The replacement doesn’t provide enough amperage.  Get a proper replacement

Answer (score 0):

It is close enough overall. Current supply is a bit low, so it will take longer to charge.

I suggest looking around a bit (eBay can help here) for a direct replacement for your model.

However the one you selected should work if you do not have any other choice. Make sure the physical connection to your device fits properly.